# gnu makefile grep, flush variable to right side

Tags: makefile, grep, cut

I have a variable in a textfile that could look like these three alternatives (1-3 chars):

```
variable=XXX
variable=V3
variable=U
```

In my makefile, I read this variable in with grep

```
VAR=$(shell grep -w "variable=" textfile.txt | cut -c 10-13)
```

Question:

But I want to to have this variable VAR "right-handed" which means that if variable=U then VAR[0]="", VAR[1]="", VAR[2]="U".

Comment: May I ask what you're trying to accomplish at a greater scale? Whitespace in variables is almost always useless in `make`, so there might be a better approach to your underlying problem. On a side note, there might be better approaches for reading your file as well (e.g. just `include` it if there are only variable definitions inside, which would be valid `make` syntax)

Comment: 1. makefile reads textfile
2. makefile writes the variable to a header file
3. A lot of script of is using the variable in the header file

. Since A lot of script is using the variable it would be better if the formatting of the variable was performed before putting the variable in the header file rather than that every script need to modify the variable. The reason that is must be right-handed is a design decision for some generation of documents and other stuffs.

Comment: Then how about letting some script generate this header file? You could use a normal `make` rule for that, so your script only executes if an input file changed.

Comment: Sorry but I have no idea what you mean by "right-handed", and the example you give doesn't make sense to me.  `VAR` is a make variable so it doesn't support subscripts, so I don't know what you intend by `VAR[0]`, `VAR[1]`, etc.  I also don't understand, given your example, why the first and seconds words would be empty and the third would be `U`?  Maybe I just haven't had my tea yet today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have [printf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/printf.1.html) available you could simply use...

```
VAR=$(shell printf '%3s' `grep -w "variable=" textfile.txt | cut -c 10-13`)
```

Comment: This command works! If variable=U the command will return VAR="  U". Next trick is to extract first, second and third char from the string VAR. Im not sure ow to do that right now.